# Installation for Mac and Linux on a windows machine

Tags: linux, macos, installation

I was wondering if there is anyway to create an installation for Mac and Linux using a strictly windows machine?  I am developing a program that I will be attempting to make available on all three platforms through use of the Mono project (C#) and need to create installers for each one. Given my almost complete ingnorance (this is a terrible I know, and I am working on rememdying this problem as well, but that is not really relevent to the question) about the non-windows platforms I am not even sure where to start looking for information.  For Windows I will be making the MSI using WiX if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention whether you are prepared to pay for a product or not. There are a few multi platform installers like InstallAnywhere which used to have a cut down free version but they now seem to be predominantly commercial & proprietary.([link to wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software))

Comment: I am not overly thrilled about paying for it given my budget constraints (I have on budget :P ), but if there are no free tools out there then I have to do what I have to do I guess...

Answer (score 1):

InstallJammer might be worth a look.

http://installjammer.com/

Lots of features, easy to use, windows and linux. No mac support yet, but they're working on it.

Comment: Looks pretty good, but Mac is the one that I am having the most trouble with. I am working a little bit with Linux so figuring that out shouldn't be a huge undertaking, but Mac I have no access to and no lust either.

Answer (score 0):

I am told [MonoTools](http://mono-tools.com/) has some kind of wizard for generating installers for various platforms, but it is $99. MonoTools is an extension to Visual Studio.

Comment: I already have MonoDevelop for creating the programs themselves. I don't have it on this computer, but I can check if it has anything built into it for just this purpose.  I honestly didn't even think of that :P

Comment: MonoTools is not the same MonoDevelop.

Comment: seems to work towards the same end.  What are the main differences (besides Visual Studio Integration)?

Comment: @Adkins, I am told it has some kind of wizard for generating installers for various platforms.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that. Cause if I go this route I would have to buy a version of VS (MonoTools doesn't work on Express) and then buy this for $99 as well.  Lot of money to be throwing around based on what you have heard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're distributing your program in source form, then [CMake](http://cmake.org/) is a great tool to automatically detect libraries and generate the proper source building stuff (makefiles, XCode projects, Visual Studio projects, etc.) on all the platforms you mention.

For creating binaries for distribution, and testing your program in other OSes, perhaps the simplest thing is just to run the other OSes in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), or something similar? I develop in Linux, but if I want to test if my cross-platform program works properly in Windows, I run an instance of that OS in VirtualBox and try it out.

Comment: and what if I will be distributing the finished product, not the source?

Comment: @Adkins: That's what the second half of what I wrote is about.

Comment: that is true, but you fail to mention how to create the actual distribution files.  You simply state a method of testing.

Comment: @Adkins: You're absolutely right. I'm sorry :-)   I'll leave my answer since someone else may find the source part useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com)  It is a commercial product but we offer free licenses for Open Source projects and also have discounts for small companies and microISVs (just ping us if it is of interest). We have several companies which ship Mono products.

Comment: The link to your other company could only be seen as an advert.